# .htaccess redirect to sub domain using URL parameter smaller than specific IDs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect http://example.org/10 to http://sub.example.org/10
I need to redirect the URLs that smaller than 194433 and the greater than remain in http://example.org/10 and not redirecting.
any idea?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to do in .htaccess even if it's possible at all.

Comment: What Apache version? With 2.4, I think that could be done using [expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) - those offer operators for integer comparison. If you combine that with `SetEnvIf` to extract only the `10` part from the requested URI, you should have all you need.

Comment: @aycanadal is there any way to do it?

Comment: Depends on your set up, and the requirement. Is it business logic or is it for load balancing or what? Is it rest or server side rendering?

Comment: @aycanadal its for load balancing.

Comment: try 04FS's answer with expressions then.